# How can I write a parameter in .CSV file (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, csv, button, android-edittext

I don't know how can I write a parameter or a line in a .csv File when I press a button in my app.
I have this in my code, but I'm not sure if I need create another class or doing it in the method onCreate. When I press the button the app stop and I don't know what is wrong.

```
EditText newParam;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_parametros);

        Button btnAgrParam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_AgrParam);
      btnAgrParam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    newParam = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.label_NewParam);
                    try{

                        String csv ="C:\\Users\\Rubén\\Desktop\\Universidad\\TFG\\Plantilla.csv";
                        CSVWriter writer;
                        writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));
                        String parametro = newParam.getText().toString();
                        String datos = parametro;
                        writer.writeNext(datos);

                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
}
```

Here is the stack trace.

11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at com.example.tfg.MenuParametros$2.onClick(MenuParametros.java:64) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 11-02 18:57:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(9861): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Post the stack trace so we can see the crash

Comment: There's something wrong with your build environment. Your CSV library is not getting packaged into your APK.

Comment: Even beyond the immediate problem, you can't directly write to your window's machine's C drive from an app running on an Android device anyway.

Comment: I'm ussing OpenCSV library but I only added in the Java Build Path. I don't have to do anything else, right?
And Chris, if I can't write in C, where do I need to have the .csv file?